# How to run CI stage conditionally

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci

I have few stages to run which are:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test-sast
  - deploy
```

in the above stage `test-sast` I have around 8 jobs to run but I want to run this stage only on a particular branch

So one possible solution is to go to each job of the stage `test-sast` and add condition i.e.

```yaml
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^release-.*/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    when: never
```

but If I do so then I need to make changes to each job i.e. at 8 places, instead is it possible to add a similar condition to the stage `test-sast` directly so that I can make the change only at a single place and it would be easy to maintain for me.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) templates and add them to each job, and have one central place in the `.test-rules:template` to handle the `rules`.

```
.test-rules:template:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^release-.*/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      when: never


test-sast-1:
  stage: test-sast
  extends:
    - .test-rules:template
  script:
    - echo "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Merge Key Language-Independent Type for YAML version 1.1. as shown below;

```
.master_only: &master_only
    rules:
        - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^release-.*/ || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
          when: never


test-sast-1:
  stage: test-sast
  # put your relevant statements here
  <<: *master_only
```